# How to login a user automatically after registration in FormView with Django?

Tags: django, authentication, formview

i have a registration form with FormView from the form class UserCreateForm. It workf fine but now I need login the user automatically after register, i have the next code:

```
class RegisterView(FormView):
    form_class = UserCreateForm
    template_name = 'contadores/register.html'
    success_url = '/contadores/create/'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/contadores/create')
        else:
            return super(RegisterView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self,form):
        user = form.save()
        user = authenticate(username=request.POST['username'],password=request.POST['password'])
        login(self.request,user)
        return super(RegisterView,self).form_valid(form)
```

I have tried with clean_data instead request.POST but anyway give an error, i also tried with login(self.request,form.user_cache) in the form_valid function but i cant get it. Question is: How can i get this?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calling `login()` method, manually set the session cookies.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    user = form.save()
    user = authenticate(username=self.request.POST['username'],password=self.request.POST['password'])
    request.session['_auth_user_id'] = user.pk
    request.session['_auth_user_backend'] = user.backend
    return super(RegisterView, self).form_valid(form)
```

**Update**

I messed up when I last updated the code above. I have updated it yet again. This is what you have to do.

1. Change `form_valid(self, request, form)` back to `form_valid(self, form)`.
2. Replace `request.POST['username']` with `self.request.POST['username']`.
3. Replace `request.POST['password']` with `self.request.POST['password']`.

Comment: Oh, that's because you have to pass `request` to `form_valid()`. Updated answer.

Comment: thanks, but i think i have to pass the request to Super(RegisterView,self).form_valid(form), since im new with django (and python) where i should pass the request? Because django says is missing one argument

Comment: @user2921575 Got it. Updated the answer. Should work fine this time.

Comment: hey pal, im can get it works, i did all that you indicated me but still it does not works... :(. It says:

Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value: 
"'password'"

Comment: That exception means the `POST` request does not have a `password`. Are you certain that form is being submitted *properly*?

Comment: Sure because before to want login the user after registration, the password worked fine.